# mod_rewrite - How to pass requesting host along with variables?

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, host

I'm using mod_rewrite to handle the request for a Javascript file that is actually PHP:

```
RewriteRule ^file.js$ file.php [L]
```

So, the code that someone puts on a site is something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//domain.com/file.js?id=1"></script>
```

The file.php file needs the "id=1" variable, but it also needs the host (domain) of the site that's making the request for the file, because we need to only allow certain domains to access it. This isn't something that we can manually update the .htaccess file with (it has to be run from a database lookup of allowed domains).

So, how do I pass along the host / domain that's requesting this file? Using $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] seems highly unreliable, and I'm hoping there's a way the .htaccess / mod_rewrite can grab it and pass it along with the other variables?

Comment: `%{http_referer}` is how htaccess gets the referrer, but it would be the same thing passed to the $_SERVER php variable.

Comment: The HTTP Refer[r]er _is_ unreliable, there is nothing you can do about that. (If you get any at all, with user’s blocking it out of privacy concern and it not being send in some HTTPS situations at all.) There _is_ no way of client-side securing this in the way you want (unless you can set up a complex shared session mechanism between your site and the site that will embed the script).